# Check selection in drop down and if it is equal to win / lose than add to stats page

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to have a drop down that has Win/Lose and then I want to check if the selection is equal to win or lose, and if it is NYKZ/AKZ/LKZ and then add to the correct cell data in another tab. Is this possible?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this isn't the cleanest answer, but it may help you...
Cell E2 has the following formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   IF(D2:D3="WINNERS",{COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER($A$2:$A,$A$2:$A="WIN", $B$2:$B=E1))),
                       COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER($A$2:$A,$A$2:$A="WIN", $B$2:$B=F1))),
                       COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER($A$2:$A,$A$2:$A="WIN", $B$2:$B=G1)))},
   IF(D2:D3="LOSERS", {COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER($A$2:$A,$A$2:$A="LOSE",$B$2:$B=E1))),
                       COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER($A$2:$A,$A$2:$A="LOSE",$B$2:$B=F1))),
                       COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER($A$2:$A,$A$2:$A="LOSE",$B$2:$B=G1)))},"SOME ERROR")))
```

[image]

See a sample sheet here...
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xBc58TtIZ3TThXv_Q9LKdcaUKlgxfzIff8LB7cLw8ks/edit?usp=sharing

Let me know if you have any questions, or if this isn't what you were expecting.

**Some Explanation**:

I used an ArrayFormula, since this will fill in all the cells required, E2 to G3.

The first `IF` is to check if I'm filling in the cells on row 2, E2:G2.  If yes, I produce an array, using "{...}", of three cells.  The first cell gets a count of the data rows, filtered by rows with "Win" in column A, AND, with values in column B equal to E1 ("NKYZ").
The second cell filters for F1 ("LKZ"), and the third cell for G1 ("AKZ").

Then the arrayformula continues, checking if it is now on D3.
It again produces three cells in an array, this time filtering the data rows for "Lose" in column A.

Let me know if any of this is still unclear.

Comment: Hey thank you this does exactly what I want. I have to say I am a bit confused as to why it works but it does! TY

Comment: Hi Kirkg. Not sure if you will check back here but is there a way to make this work across sheets so the A and B columns would be on a different tab than the stats. I am struggling to get it to work

Comment: Look at Sheet2 in my sample sheet.  Is that what you want?  If not, you'll have to explain more clearly, and provide a sample sheet showing what you want and where...

Comment: Ty yes it was. No idea why it worked for you and not me as I had the same thing I think. Eitherway TYVM again!

Comment: Man I keep thinking im good to go but somehow I keep messing this up. I have altered your example sheet. I added a stats sheet that is a duplicate of how it looks exactly in my sheet and I added a Log sheet that is the same. I posted my formula in the sheet itself but I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: @arkad, The formula you modified in B4 looks at the right data, in Log, but you didn't update it to look for the three headings - NYKZ, LKZ, and AKZ - in their new location. 
  See my formula just below yours in Stats.  Note they could also be hard-coded in the formula, if you preferred.  Eg. "NYKZ" instead of B3.

Comment: ah i knew it was something silly i was doing wrong. Ty again!